# Revision history of the moderator-editable parts of /helpcenter

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, revisions-list, help-center

The moderator-editable part of the `/faq` used to have a 'history' link (visible only to moderators) that allowed moderators to see past revisions of that part. There doesn’t seem to be any such link now, with the new `/helpcenter`. Can there be?

Comment: Anyone remember the url to the old revisions page?

Comment: @DoubleAA I *think* it was the regular `/posts/N/revisions` page (with some specific post number that, I'm guessing, varied from site to site). I may be misremembering.

Comment: @double you can use data.SE and look for posts with a PostTypeID of iirc 7. Or you  can try to edit it and get the post id from the textarea id. Once you have that, `/posts/<id>/revisions` ought to work.

Comment: It'll be a new URL now anyway, @Double AA - for instance, [old](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/7352/revisions), [new](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/29206/revisions)

Comment: Type 7 is the old FAQ wikis; the new help topics are Type 10 @Manishearth.

Comment: @shog good to know, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moderators should now be able to view the revision history for any moderator-editable page in the help center. (For most sites, this is just the "What topics can I ask about here?" article.)

Moderators should see a link called "history" at the bottom of any mod-editable article; clicking that link will take you to a page that displays any changes made to the post.