# Can we add the last update date for each page on Help Center?

Tags: feature-request, help-center, localization, timestamps, dates

Some help pages are site-specific. In particular, on non-English sites, the content of help pages are written (translated) obviously later than its original sources.

To detect outdated pages (e.g., we can compare the dates on English and non-English sites), the last update timestamp could be really helpful. Some pages (like moderator-related help) could not be compared with other sites since it's not visible if you don't have moderator privileges on that site.

Could we please add the last update date somewhere to help page?

It looks like we have at least one page with a published update date, but that page is actually located on the different URL path than other help pages. However, it's [referenced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/stackexchange) from the Help Center. It's the [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Comment: related: [How can I find the revisions history for the help center?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378446/997587)